# How to fix css links in Laravel project on Linux?

Tags: css, linux, laravel, ubuntu, frontend

I worked on some Laravel project on Windows and in css files (that located in `public/assets/css`) i created links to fonts and images like this: `url("/assets/images/banners/eco.png");` When i moved to Ubuntu 20.4 and loaded this project to localhost (lamp server), css links toped working.[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move that images folder to `/public` directory. then change your urls to point to the folder